# rest api expected response for GET

Tags: api, rest, http-response-codes

I am working on making a rest api and I have a question about what is typically returned from a get with no match.  For instance if my resource is "users" and I make an api call with

http method: GET
url: api.mysite.com/users/123

If '123' exists I will return a http code of 200 with the details of the user in the response body.  My question is; what http code should I return, and what should I put in the response body if there is no user with the id of 123?

Should I just return a code of 200 and an empty body?

Comment: 404 for sure! Read jeresy documentation, there are example for 404:  *If a user name does not match that a 404 (Not Found) response will occur.* https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **404**, because requested resource (User) not exist.

> **10.4.5 404 Not Found**

> **The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI**. No
> indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
> permanent. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
> knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
> resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
> This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
> reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
> response is applicable. [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5)

- [Better Rest API design 2](http://hao-deng.blogspot.com/2013/06/better-rest-api-design-2.html)
- [RESTful resource not found. 404 or 204? Jersey returns 204 on null being returned from handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195639/restful-resource-not-found-404-or-204-jersey-returns-204-on-null-being-returne)
- [When to use HTTP status code 404 in an API](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203492/when-to-use-http-status-code-404-in-an-api)

Comment: @MariuszS What would I do if I have a url like https://api.mysite.com/users which is supposed to return a collection of users.  But in my http body I include {"hair":"green"} which I use to select only users with green hair.  What status code would I return then?  Would it be a 404, or would it be 200 with an empty return.  I am confused because the hair:green parameter isn't part of the url, but it is part of the http body.

Comment: Please add new question for this. In general request for users should by `GET`, with query string `?hair=green` and result status code should be `200` with empty collection `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

As its your API, so you can return whatever you want but if you talked about the standard of HTTP responses than I would suggest you to return `404 (NOT FOUND)` in that case which looks more suitable in this case. Because the resource you are trying to access is not available at that location.

[404- Not Found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) implies the server has not found anything matching the Request-URI.

With status code 404 you can also provide the response body or any other meaningful header with proper error message. So that client can understand it.

Comment: No, that's really really wrong. HTTP codes should be used for HTTP transport responses - 200 OK doesn't represent *data or data* it represents *successful response*. 404 means *not found* as in the *endpoint* you're trying to reach is not found.

Comment: @remus This is Rest Service with specific content, not web page. If content not exist then 404 is best message for client.

Comment: @MariuszS ok, then how would you differentiate between *endpoint* not found and *no content* with the same HTTP code?

Comment: 404 is completely appropriate if the resource identified by the URI is not found. If by "endpoint not found" you are referring to a service that doesn't support the operation (e.g. GET or POST) on that particular URI, then the appropriate response would be 405 (Method not Allowed)