# Status Code 204 coming while accessing a resource which does not exist in Database

Tags: mysql, rest, jdbc, jersey

In my MySQL database, I have a table named Messages which is having 4 rows , with unique message ID as 1,2,3,4.

When using REST Api I am accessing collection resource:

http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages

I am getting all the message entries as JSON , which is expected;
Please find below :

```
[
    {
        "author": "Vineet",
        "creation": "09/12/2017",
        "id": 1,
        "message": "Message1"
    },
    {
        "author": "Puneet",
        "creation": "09/12/2017",
        "id": 2,
        "message": "Message2"
    },
    {
        "author": "Dad",
        "creation": "09/12/2017",
        "id": 3,
        "message": "Message3"
    },
    {
        "author": "Mom",
        "creation": "09/12/2017",
        "id": 4,
        "message": "Message4"
    }
]
```

When using REST Api I am accessing the individual resource:

http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/1 or
http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/2 or
http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/3 or
http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/4

I am getting the expected response for every single resource e.g. for 1

```
{
        "author": "Vineet",
        "creation": "09/12/2017",
        "id": 1,
        "message": "Message1"
 }
```

Problem : When I am trying to access url :

http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/9 , where 9 is a resource that never exists in database.

I am getting a blank page or the last loaded page. and The HTTP Code coming is : 204.

When "9" id is not present , why is not there 404 message ?
Why 204 ?

Comment: What framework are you running your REST API in?  If it's Jersey, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195639/) might help.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Thanks for helping with that post. But I did not get my answer. When resource does not exists, then where does it look up and bring null value ? It should be 404 error but 204 is coming.

Comment: You haven't answered my question! Are you using Jersey for your REST API?  Or are you using something else, and if so, what?

Comment: I am sorry. Yes I am using Jersey. @LukeWoodward

Answer (score 0):

The route is correct and only the paramerter which you have provided is wrong so there is no way you will get a 404 which is page not found but the request has hit service so it a successful service hit

I hope you can handle the error in exception handling.

Comment: But the resource I am hitting does not exists. I am still confused.Anyway, could you please help in exception handling code regarding Error 204.Thanks for your help.