# Spring MVC: Throwing exception or returning NULL entity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In the `CarController` class, I have a method for getting a `Car` instance by `id`. The question is whether to throw an exception or return a `ResponseEntity<Car>(null, ...)`

**VERSION 1** Throwing exception if car's `Id` does not exist

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    private CarService service;

    @GetMapping("cars/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> getById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        try {
            Car car = service.getById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Car>(car, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch(AppException ae) {
            LOG.error("CarService could not get car with id {}", id);
            throw ae;
        }
    }

}
```

**VERSION 2** Returning null `Car` in ResponseEntity if id can't be found

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    private CarService service;

    @GetMapping("cars/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> getById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        try {
            Car car = service.getById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Car>(car, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (AppException ae) {
            LOG.error("CarService could not get car with id {}", id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Car>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Second version is better. But instead of null you cna just do this 

`return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reccomend using the null element in combination with the HTTP/404 Status code.

If you simply throw an exception, the error handling is most likely to produce a 5XX-HTTP Status code, which means that there is an internal server error. However in your case, there should not be an internal server error, because the resource is simply not found.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2195675/6085896 (In this case the question is 2XX-Status vs 4XX-Status)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@RestController
public class CarController {

    @Autowired
    private CarService service;

    @GetMapping("cars/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Car> getById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        Car car = service.getById(id);
        if (car == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Car>(car, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        LOG.info("Car has id {} is not exist.", id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Car>(null, headers, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

because Return no object, it is not the same meaning with an `Exception`, return `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` is good enough.

Comment: I believe you meant `if (car == null)`